# How to listen to a jQuery trigger in legacy js

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I'm triggering an event with jquery and I need to bind to it in a non jQuery script.

It seems that I can bind to the event in jQuery with `on` but not with `addEventListener`.

Here is a jsFiddle showing that: http://jsfiddle.net/x6rhT/

How may I listen for a jQuery event with `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events):

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('test'));
```

You could easily create a wrapper:

```
$.fn.nativeTrigger = function(type) {
    return this.each(function() {
        this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent(type) );
    });
}

$('body').trigger('test').nativeTrigger('test');
```

Another way would be to extend the `$.fn.trigger` but that’s pretty deep water.

Comment: If I understand well, this if to trigger the event in js? I want a way to listen to a jQuery trigger in js.

Comment: See my edit. I would create a separate wrapper for it, extending the `$.fn.trigger` could easily cause more trouble than it’s worth.

Comment: I get the Idea. It's not very practical in my case because the trigger is done with jquery widget factory `_trigger`. Any idea why the events aren't "compatible"?